# I can't choose between two installed ubuntus

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Ubuntu 16.04 using the option:

**Install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**

But when it completes the installation and I restart the computer, I cannot choose between these two Ubuntus and it runs only the 16.04 version.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

To point you in the right direction, you should install a bootmanager such as grub. Grub will then loaded at boot and lets you choose which OS you want to boot

Comment: During the installation it gets the grub.and when i choose to install another  ubuntu, it says there two ubuntus... but i can not access one of them...

Comment: You could try to run the command `update-grub` and see if that helps. That command re-creates the configuration files, so if something went wrong previously during installation it might be solved after recreation.

Comment: where should i enter the command?!

Comment: I might have misunderstood what you meant. Can't you access one of them, or can't you access any one of them? If you can access one, boot into that one and enter the command there. If you cannot access any of them, try booting onto a live-usb/cd and create the grub config in there.

Answer (score 0):

simply run this command in terminal, it will check any other installed OS and list it's entry on boot menu

```
sudo update-grub
```